# Что значит запись типа 0x00

Tags: c++, микроконтроллеры, байткод

открыл библиотеку для модуля на ардуины, там имеет место запись типа

```
#define ADDR_MASK        0x1F
```

Это `1F` я так понимаю какой-то байт в шестнадцатеричной системе исчисления , а что такое `0x` и зачем оно нужно ?

Comment: Это просто общепринятый маркер шестнадцатиричной системы

Comment: [В Си и языках схожего синтаксиса, например, в Java, используют префикс «0x». Например, «0x5A3».](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шестнадцатеричная_система_счисления)

Comment: 0x - это префикс, обозначающий что далее следует число записанное в шестнадцатеричной системе. Записать 1F так же можно, но, значить это будет вкорне другое - F уже играет роль постфикса, обозначающего float число, отсюда 1F = 1, а 0x1F = 31. И в целом - это не относится к микроконтроллерам, и не относится к байткоду. Это основы языка, который вам необходимо было изучить...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это обычный интегральный литерал, записанный в шестнадцатиричной системе счисления. Есть и другие префиксы, подробнее можно посмотреть в соответствующем разделе:
[integral literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), [character literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal), [floating literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) и т.д.